# Calling a void method in java

Tags: java, android, methods, call

I am new to Java and looked around for answers on this without any luck. I am trying to call a method from another without any luck.

I have this in my protected onCreate

```
    final RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    rlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mLevelTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);
            mLevelTextView.setText(Integer.toString(clickCounter));

            yellowLevelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yellowLevel);
            yellowLevelText.setText(Integer.toString((clickCounter - 1) / 256 + 1));
            //this is what I am trying to call but get an error
            savedInfo();

            rlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + decToHex(colorNumber)));
            colorNumber = new Integer(colorNumber - 1);
            clickCounter = new Integer(clickCounter + 1);
        }

    });
```

And this is the method at the end of my code I am trying to call:

```
    public void saveInfo(View view) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("score", 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("totalScore", clickCounter);
    editor.putInt("yellowScore", yellowCounter);
    editor.putInt("magentaScore", magentaCounter);
    editor.putInt("cyanScore", cyanCounter);
    editor.apply();
}
```

The error I am getting is this:
error: method saveInfo in class startup cannot be applied to given types;
required: View
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Anyone with more experience able to see what might be wrong here?

Comment: You're trying to call `saveInfo()`. You need to call `saveInfo(someView)`.

Comment: `savedInfo()` takes an argument. Apart from that You did not used argument in method so just remove it . Make it simple as ` public void saveInfo() `

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `saveInfo()`. You need to call `saveInfo(someView)`.

Although actually, your `saveInfo` method doesn't do anything with that parameter, so just remove it. The method signature should be:

```
public void saveInfo() {
```

Comment: @rmlan True. Maybe that's just a typo. The compiler error clearly states  that `saveInfo` is being called incorrectly.

Comment: Oh, silly me. I didn't read that far and didn't see that OP actually posted the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

you execute method `saveInfo` without any argument. You have to pass  argument of type `View`

Comment: this should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Pass on click view into method .. v

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mLevelTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);
        mLevelTextView.setText(Integer.toString(clickCounter));

        yellowLevelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yellowLevel);
        yellowLevelText.setText(Integer.toString((clickCounter - 1) / 256 + 1));
        //this is what I am trying to call but get an error
        savedInfo(v);

        rlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + decToHex(colorNumber)));
        colorNumber = new Integer(colorNumber - 1);
        clickCounter = new Integer(clickCounter + 1);
    }

});
```